# Behavior of `text` property in a page record / property in Notion

Tags: notion-api

Going through the Notion API docs, it mentions the [text configuration](https://developers.notion.com/reference/database#text-configuration) is same as rich-text-object.
In the response for my page, I view the text property as -

```
{
"object": "page",
"id": "123",
"created_time": "2021-02-18T15:12:00.000Z",
"last_edited_time": "2021-05-15T12:37:30.830Z",
"parent": {
    "type": "database_id",
    "database_id": "456"
},
"archived": false,
"properties": {
    "Highlights": {
        "id": "jCaG",
        "type": "text",
        "text": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": {
                    "content": "test 1\ntest 2",
                    "link": null
                },
                "annotations": {
                    "bold": false,
                    "italic": false,
                    "strikethrough": false,
                    "underline": false,
                    "code": false,
                    "color": "default"
                },
                "plain_text": "test 1\ntest 2",
                "href": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My question is, if the `text` property takes an array, can we add multiple text objects to it?

I tried to do the same with the `PATCH` request to the [update page record](https://developers.notion.com/reference/patch-page), but the response was not as expected, it switched all the annotations to `true`, ie. bold, italic, underline, strike-through and code blocks all were true, even though they weren't in the initial request.

Here, is the JSON I sent in my `PATCH` call -

```
{
"object": "page",
"id": "123",
"created_time": "2021-02-18T15:12:00.000Z",
"last_edited_time": "2021-05-15T12:09:00.000Z",
"parent": {
    "type": "database_id",
    "database_id": "456"
},
"archived": false,
"properties": {
    "Highlights": {
        "id": "jCaG",
        "type": "text",
        "text": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": {
                    "content": "test 1\ntest 2",
                    "link": null
                },
                "annotations": {
                    "bold": false,
                    "italic": false,
                    "strikethrough": false,
                    "underline": false,
                    "code": false,
                    "color": "default"
                },
                "plain_text": "test 1\ntest 2",
                "href": null
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": {
                    "content": "test 3",
                    "link": null
                },
                "annotations": {
                    "bold": false,
                    "italic": false,
                    "strikethrough": false,
                    "underline": false,
                    "code": false,
                    "color": "default"
                },
                "plain_text": "test 3",
                "href": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And the response from the same was -

```
{
"object": "page",
"id": "123",
"created_time": "2021-02-18T15:12:00.000Z",
"last_edited_time": "2021-05-15T12:37:30.830Z",
"parent": {
    "type": "database_id",
    "database_id": "456"
},
"archived": false,
"properties": {
    "Highlights": {
        "id": "jCaG",
        "type": "text",
        "text": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": {
                    "content": "test 1\ntest 2",
                    "link": null
                },
                "annotations": {
                    "bold": true,
                    "italic": true,
                    "strikethrough": true,
                    "underline": true,
                    "code": true,
                    "color": "default"
                },
                "plain_text": "test 1\ntest 2",
                "href": null
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": {
                    "content": "test 3",
                    "link": null
                },
                "annotations": {
                    "bold": true,
                    "italic": true,
                    "strikethrough": true,
                    "underline": true,
                    "code": true,
                    "color": "default"
                },
                "plain_text": "test 3",
                "href": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Has anyone here experimented with the text property, if yes, can you please guide me through the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a call you can test to play with rich_text. This should work as long as you have your database set-up with a text column called "sample_text". It should work as you would expect.

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/YOUR_PAGE_ID' \
--header 'Notion-Version: 2021-05-13' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_BOT_SECRET' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
   "parent":{
      "database_id":"DATABASE_ID"
   },
   "properties":{
      "Name":{
         "title":[
            {
               "text":{
                  "content":"A Test Page"
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "sample_text":{
         "rich_text":[
            {
               "type":"text",
               "text":{
                  "content":"Some more text with "
               }
            },
            {
               "type":"text",
               "text":{
                  "content":"some"
               },
               "annotations":{
                  "italic":true,
                  "bold": false,
                  "underline": false,
                  "strikethrough": true,
                  "color": "blue"
               }
            },
            {
               "type":"text",
               "text":{
                  "content":" "
               }
            },
            {
               "type":"text",
               "text":{
                  "content":"fun"
               },
               "annotations":{
                  "bold":true,
                  "underline": false,
                  "strikethrough": false
               }
            },
            {
               "type":"text",
               "text":{
                  "content":" "
               }
            },
            {
               "type":"text",
               "text":{
                  "content":"formatting"
               },
               "annotations":{
                  "color":"pink"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}'
```